# ios simulator not booting up in macos catalina running under oracle virtual box - react native expo project

Tags: macos, react-native, expo, virtualbox, macos-catalina

run the react-native expo project using the virtual box in macOS catalina.
run the ios simulator.
simulator long time showing apple icon not booting up.
in the macOS Catalina environment.

system error message in the simulator
service exited due to sigill | send by exc handler 2147

Please find the image below for your reference.
[image: iPhone simulator not starting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling AVX/AVX2 solved for me

Open cmd

cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"

VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX 0
VBoxManage setextradata "$vm_name" VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 0